# How to use Sitecore Solr Custom Index

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore

Could someone please help me understand below?

1. Do we need to specify the name of the index in code when using a Sitecore solr search?
2. If we make the new custom index called 'sitecore_web-index_custom'. How do we make sure we are using this index in code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get Sitecore index, use `GetIndex` method from the `ContentSearchManager` class:

```cs
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(...)
```

You can either pass index name:

```cs
// get Sitecore built in index for current database:
string dbName = (Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase ?? Sitecore.Context.Database).Name;
var index = Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_" + dbName + "_index");

// get custom index
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web-index_custom")
```

or Sitecore Item:

```cs
// get index by Sitecore item 
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex((SitecoreIndexableItem)item);
```

In the second scenario, Sitecore will try to find the index in which the item is indexed.

There is no difference between getting **Solr** or **Lucene** indexes - Sitecore API is transparent here.

More information about Sitecore search and indexing can be found in

- [Sitecore Search and Indexing Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/sitecore_search_and_indexing_guide_sc75-a4.pdf)
- [Developer's Guide to Item Buckets and Search](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/developer's_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc7-a4.pdf)